# Property fields are not shown in popup dialog, why?

Tags: python, scripting

I am attempting to learn Blender and therefore following some Youtube "courses"...
The below code should present a popup dialog with two property fields.

```
import bpy

class WM_OT_myOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Open the Add Cube Dialog Box"""
    bl_label = "Add Cube Dialog Box"
    bl_idname = "wm.myop"
    
    text = bpy.props.StringProperty(name= "Enter Text", default = "")
    number = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name = "Scale Z Axis", default = 1)
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_myOp)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_myOp)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register() 
    
    bpy.ops.wm.myop('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

However, in my case what I see is this:

[image]

The fields for text and number do never show up. Anyone to tell me why?

Comment: replace `=` with `:` in the property definitions eg `text: bpy.props.StringProperty(name= "Enter Text", default = "")`

Comment: Using ':' definitely did the trick. Thanks so much!!
However, the guy in the video definitely used '=*, *not: ':'.
How did he manage? Something changed?

Comment: It changed when 2.80 released if I'm not mistaken, if you tutorial is more than 2 years old that's why :)